# Page refreshes after the dropdown value is selected in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react component:

```
     
    class RenderChart extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
       
        this.selectValue=this.selectValue.bind(this);
        this.selectValueYear1=this.selectValueYear1.bind(this)
      
        this.state={
         
          isLoaded:false,
          
          items_y1: [],
          items_y2: [],
          items_y12: [],
          arr_keys:[],
          arr_vals:[],
          
          selectValue2:"",
          selectVal:"",
          
          data:[],
        }
      }
     
   
    
      selectValueYear1(e){
          this.setState({
              selectVal:e.value
          })
      }
      selectValue (e) {
        
        var selectVal=this.state.selectVal;
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/values/"+selectVal+"/"+e.value)
            .then(response =>  response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    
                  items_y1:json.commontopics,
                  
                  isLoaded:true
                  
                  
                })            
            });
    
        
        
        
      };
    
      
      
    
      
      
         
     
          render() {
            
    
            var {isLoaded,desc,selectValue2,selectVal,items_y1} = this.state;
            
           
           
            const data = [
              {
                value: "2011",
                label: "2011"
              },
              {
                value: "2012",
                label: "2012"
              },
              {
                value: "2013",
                label: "2013"
              },
              {
                value: "2014",
                label: "2014"
              },
              {
                value: "2015",
                label: "2015"
              },
              {
                value: "2016",
                label: "2016"
              },
              {
                value: "2017",
                label: "2017"
              },
              {
                value: "2018",
                label: "2018"
              },
              {
                value: "2019",
                label: "2019"
              },
              {
                value: "2020",
                label: "2020"
              }
            ];
          
            
            
           
            
    
            
            
            
          
            
    
    
            
            
            
            if(isLoaded){
            
              return (
                <>
        
              
              <br></br>
                            
           
                 
                  <React.Fragment>
                  
                  <Row>
                            <Col>
                            <Label>Select an Year</Label>
                            <Select  placeholder="Select Option" options={data} value={data.find(obj => obj.value === selectVal)} 
                            onChange={this.selectValueYear1}
                             />
                             </Col>
                             <Col>
                             <Label>Select an Year</Label>
                            <Select  placeholder="Select Option" options={data} value={data.find(obj => obj.value === selectValue2)} 
                             onChange={this.selectValue}/>
                             </Col>
                             </Row>
                             <br></br>
                             <br></br>
                            
                  <Row>
                 
                  {console.log("items",items_y1)}
                  <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${items_y1}`}></img> 
                  </Row>
    
                  </React.Fragment>
                </>
              );
              } 
            else{
              return (
              <>
              <Row>
                            <Col>
                            <Label>Select an Year</Label>
                            <Select  placeholder="Select Option" options={data} value={data.find(obj => obj.value === selectVal)} 
                            onChange={this.selectValueYear1}
                             />
                             </Col>
                             <Col>
                             <Label>Select an Year</Label>
                            <Select  placeholder="Select Option" options={data} value={data.find(obj => obj.value === selectValue2)} 
                             onChange={this.selectValue}/>
                             </Col>
                             </Row>
              </>
              )
            } 
           
          }
    }
    
    export default RenderChart ;
```

I have two dropdowns to select values from.When I select a value from second dropdown,image is rendered and page is refreshed.I don't understand why page is being refreshed.Also,this is a component inside another component.and there are many other child components

Comment: do u mean re-render or refresh?

Comment: Can you clean up your code a bit? Please show the code that you think is related to the problem. Also what is your attempt to debug your problem?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial not sure whether re-render or refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding e.preventDefault() in your function

```js
selectValue (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var selectVal=this.state.selectVal;
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/values/"+selectVal+"/"+e.value)
            .then(response =>  response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({                   
                  items_y1:json.commontopics,                  
                  isLoaded:true 
                })            
            });  
      };
```